# WampServer 2.1 nao abre o localhost, o phpadmin nem fica verde

Tags: servidor, wamp

Instalei o wampserver 2.1 e desde entçao não consigo abrir o phpadmim nem o meu localhost, na instalação foi sem mexer em nenhuma configuração.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Que cor ele fica? Vermelho, laranja? Geralmente o Wamp Server entra em conflito com o Skype por usar as mesmas portas, tente fechar o Skype totalmente ou mudar as portas...

Comment: na cor Laranja direto, mas eu nao tenho o skype

Comment: Vai em Apache/Service > Test Port 80. Faz o teste pra ver "quem" está usando a porta.

Comment: Diz: your port 80 is not actually used

Comment: Acho que você já fez isso, mas caso contrário tente reiniciar todos os serviços, se não der certo coloque pra parar todos os serviços, e depois para iniciar todos os serviços...

Comment: ja fiz, sem sucesso. Ja reinstalei e nada..

Comment: Tente também: Na tray icon, Apache/Service > Install Service.

Como a porta 80 está livre ele vai pedir pra você pressionar uma tecla pra continuar, ai continue a operação e veja se deu certo...

Comment: Depois tente reiniciar todos os serviços novamente e veja se ficou verde.

Se não der certo segue o post do SOen:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon e veja se lhe ajuda!

Comment: você esta usando algum tipo de proxy no navegador? se sim tente acessa localhost.com.br